# Finding the dual of a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

> Consider the LP
>
> $min f(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i x_i $
>
> such that
>
> \begin{align*} x_1 \geq 1 \\ x_1 + x_2 \geq 2 \\ ... \\ x_1 + ... +
>  x_n \geq n  \end{align*}
>
> Im trying to find the Dual and an optimal solution to the LP

#### attempt

The dual is easy to find:

$max f = \sum_{i=1}^n i x_i $

such that

\begin{align*} x_1+x_2+...+x_n  \geq 1 \\ x_2 + ... + x_n  \geq 2 \\ ... \\ 
 x_n \geq n  \end{align*}

but, how can we find the optimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual is

$$\max_y \sum_{i=1}^n i y_i$$

subject to $$y_i \ge 0$$

$$\sum_{i=j}^n y_i = j, \forall j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$$

In particular, for $n>1$, we have $$y_1 +\ldots + y_n =1$$

and $$y_2 +\ldots + y_n =2$$

which implies that $y_1=-1<0$ which shows that the dual is infeasible.

We can check that the primal is feasible and hence it is unbounded.

To directly see that the primal is unbounded for $n>1$, notice that $(1+k, 1, \ldots, 1, 1-k)$ is feasible for the primal. We can let $k$ be arbitrary big and the objective function will be unbounded.

Comment: Typo on the 5th line: should be $$ \sum y_i \leq j $$

Comment: I thought the $x_i$ are free variables in the primal. Hence in the dual,the variable are of equality form.

Comment: I believe $x_i \geq 0$. If so, then above attempt is correct and the optimal solution would be different

Comment: Typo in my previous comment, the constraint in the dual are of equality form if $x_i$ are free variable.